# Salesforce Canvas App Issue with Chrome Latest Versions and Recent Cookie SameSite Policy

Tags: aura, canvas, cookies, canvas-app

We created a Canvas App implementation in Salesforce that is able to render an external .NET / C# web app within the CRM by means of an aura component. It works perfectly fine in any browser, except from Chrome Latest version, more specifically after the Recent SameSite Cookie Policy changes.

We followed [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351874&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) Salesforce help official article and added the following suggested C# code to be able to keep using cookies:

```
Request.Cookies[aspNetCookieName].Secure = true;
Request.Cookies[aspNetCookieName].SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
```

The app is rendered within the canvas iframe, but the needed cookie is shown as empty when using the Chrome Inspector, and it can't be read when asked by the external app code.
Other browsers like Firefox that haven't still implemented Chrome's new feature,do not empty the abovementioned cookie, which is readable and has SameSite = None and Secure = true options.

Does anyone have any kind of suggestion, please?
Thanks in advance for your help.